# Multithreading- Function exits before thread finishes. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a function that generates database layers for a map application but since the computation takes too long I put it into a thread. However, obviously, but not to me 5 seconds ago, the function returns without it finishing the computation so the function returns nothing. Is there any way I can still have the work be sent to where it needs to go?

```
public static int calcNum()
{
 int value = 0;

 Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => {    
    value = 5;
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Simulates work being done
});


   return value; //Returns 0 when I want it to be 5 
}
```

Comment: what? you lost me

Comment: threads don't block by default. thats the point of them.

Comment: Is `calcNum` supposed to wait for the thread to finish before it returns? What's the point of creating  new thread in the first place then? You can always call `thread1.Join` before returning but then your `calcNum` method will obviously block waiting for the result...

Comment: Be aware that in your example - besides that there is nothing that waits for its outcome - the Thread is *not even started*.

Answer (score 0):

A "computation" doesn't get any faster at all just because you run it on a different thread.

If don't want your method to return before the computation has finished, you should implement your method like this without involving any additional thread:

```
public static int calcNum()
{
    int value = 0;

    value = 5;
    Thread.Sleep(5000); //Simulates work being done

    return value;
}
```

If you want to prevent the calling thread from being blocked while executing the "computation", you could implemenent an `async` method that executes the long running operation in a `Task`:

```
public static async Task<int> CalcNumAsync()
{
    int value = 0;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        value = 5;
        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Simulates work being done
    });

    return value;
}
```

You will then have to await the method when you call it:

```
int num = await CalcNumAsync();
```

The latter approach is for example useful in UI application, when you want the applicaiton to stay responsive while your long running operation is being executed on a background thread.